# list the files from internal storage android

Tags: android, arraylist

> I am currently working with internal storage

i have some problems,

- I am also get the files in particular folder on internal storage,but my list shows all root folders like `data/data/com.example.app/sample.mp4`, But i want only filename like `sample.mp4`.

> Here my code

`

```
    ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();

    File mydir = this.getDir("Myfolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File listFile[] = mydir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {

        for (File aListFile : listFile) {

            if (aListFile.isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(aListFile);

            } else {
                if (aListFile.isFile());
                {
                    fileList.add(aListFile);
                }
            }
        }`
```

Comment: You have `data/data/com.example.app/sample.mp4` but want `sample.mp4`? That is just some simple string parsing to remove the front of the string so please explain what difficulty you have in this.

Comment: you can use substring method to parse what exactly you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get filename from file object

```
 if (aListFile.isFile());
 {
     string fileName = aListFile.getName();
 }
```

Comment: yes..we can easily get all kind of files name using this method

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
YourFilePath.substring(YourFilePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

> For example,

`String filePath = "data/data/com.example.app/sample.mp4"
String fileName = filePath.subString(filePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);`

And finally you get your `fileName = sample.mp4`